# Super beginners' questions, how is my code not showing in the console when I click and run it?

Tags: python

```
from main import Question

question_prompts = [
    "What is your name ?\n(a) Antti\n(b) Henri\n(c) Mika\n\n",
    "How old are you ?\n(a) 10\n(b) 20\n(c) 30\n\n",
    "How do you feel today ?\n(a) Great\n(b) Okay\n(c) Bad\n\n",

]

questions = [
    Question(question_prompts[0], "c"),
    Question(question_prompts[1], "c"),
    Question(question_prompts[2], "c"),
]


def run_test(questions):
    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        answer = input(question.prompt)
        if answer == question.answer:
            score += 1
    print("You got " + str(score) + "/" + str(len(questions)) + "Correct")


run_test(questions)
```

**I copied exactly from that popular youtube tutorial, but mine is not generating anything.
Really appreciated your answer.**

Comment: What are you running your code in? Terminal or an IDE? This is a very badly detailed question, please add some details. Just a simple "why won't it show up" is not a good question.

Comment: Maybe the console closes immediately after code execution. How about you add another input("hit enter to close") call at the end of your program ? You also might consider using cmd.exe console app and call python with the filename as parameter from there like: 'python3 question.py'...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I run it on an IDE

Comment: Are you sure you're running *this* file, rather than the `main.py` that it imports?  Looks like that file just contains a class definition, so it probably wouldn't do anything if you ran it directly.

Comment: @jasonharper, I copied all the code, from Freecodecamp video, tips given by pycharm is "Shadows name 'questions' from outer scope ". I am fairly sure I ran this file instead of merely import.

Comment: obviously, there should be a Question class in main.py, so you should check the video

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the code here is missing the `Question` class in the `main` module ( the code show`from main import Quesion`). I speculate that the complete code might look like this:

```py
class Question:
    def __init__(self, text: str, a: str):
        # temp = text.split("\n")
        # self.prompt = temp[0]
        # self.a = temp[1]
        # self.b = temp[2]
        # self.c = temp[3]
        self.prompt = text
        self.answer = a


question_prompts = [
    "What is your name ?\n(a) Antti\n(b) Henri\n(c) Mika\n\n",
    "How old are you ?\n(a) 10\n(b) 20\n(c) 30\n\n",
    "How do you feel today ?\n(a) Great\n(b) Okay\n(c) Bad\n\n",

]

questions = [
    Question(question_prompts[0], "c"),
    Question(question_prompts[1], "c"),
    Question(question_prompts[2], "c"),
]


def run_test(questions):
    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        answer = input(question.prompt)
        if answer == question.answer:
            score += 1
    print("You got " + str(score) + "/" + str(len(questions)) + "Correct")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_test(questions)
```